# How to use bundler behind a proxy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, proxy, rubygems, bundler

I get the following output from the *sudo bundle install* command:

```
Fetching source index for `http://rubygems.org/`  
Could not reach rubygems repository `http://rubygems.org/`  
Could not find gem 'rspec-rails (>= 2.0.0.beta.22, runtime)' in any of the gem sources.
```

I have $http_proxy set correctly and I've added *gem: --http-proxy=my proxy* to ~/.gemrc. These settings are what allow my gem commands to work, and I was hoping they would translate to bundler, but no such luck.

Thinking sudo might not inherit my all of my environment, I also added those settings to my root user, but nada.

At this point bundler is preventing me from deploying my application, and I can find very few others running into this. If no one has an answer I will be forced to rip bundler out of my Rails app (which I wouldn't mind doing...)

Comment: I am also facing this issue. gem works http_proxy is set in my .profile and .gemrc, as explained in the original post On OSX, ruby 1.8.7, rubygems 1.3.7 Any ideas would be welcome :)

Comment: Hi, dont suppose you got this working?  I seem to have the same error on OSX :(

Comment: No, I've never gotten it working. I have since stripped out Bundler from my app and am loading gems manually in config/application.rb. I can hardly tell the difference.

Comment: Why isn't this working? I have the same issue over Debian.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

**OSX & Linux**

```
export http_proxy=http://user:password@host:port
export HTTP_PROXY=$http_proxy
```

If it's using HTTPS, set it as well

```
export https_proxy=http://user:password@host:port
export HTTPS_PROXY=$https_proxy
```

If you use `sudo`, by default `sudo` does not preserves http proxy variable. Use `-E` flag to preserve it

```
$ sudo -E bundle install
```

to make `sudo` preserves environment variables by default:

https://memset.wordpress.com/2010/10/14/bash-http_proxy-from-a-user-environment-to-sudo-one/

**Windows**

As pointed by answers below, you can use `SET` instead

```
SET HTTP_PROXY=http://user:password@host:port
SET HTTPS_PROXY=%HTTP_PROXY%
```

Comment: Good guess, but that's not it either.

Comment: As of (at least) bundler 1.0.12 this seems to work. Perhaps they fixed something?

Comment: it worked for me in windows box, by doing exactly same thing with "SET" command , eg `SET http_proxy=http://user:password@host:port
` and worked in cygwin too :)

Comment: ahmy's answer is the correct one. But if your username or password include special characters such as "<" or ">" (others may cause problems as well) gem will not work. Make sure to remove any of these characters (by changing your password/username) then export again. If anyone has a workaround for these characters please reply as well.

Comment: do no forget to set https_proxy

Comment: "by default sudo does not preserve http proxy." - Really important note. :) Thank you.

Comment: It worked for me on openSUSE Leap 15.0, with Ruby v2.5.0, gem v2.7.3, and Bundler v1.16.1. I've made a shell script that does `export http_proxy=...` and `export https_proxy=...` before invoking `bundle install`. As @user831217 pointed out on another comment, don't forget to set `https_proxy` too.

Answer (score 15):

I figured out that also setting HTTP_PROXY (in addition to http_proxy) made a positive difference, i.e. it worked for me. So assuming that you have set up `http_proxy` environment variable correct, try (if you are using bash)

```
export HTTP_PROXY=$http_proxy
```

and then also use the `-E` option to sudo (to preserve environment variables), so

```
sudo -E bundle install
```

Jarl

Comment: This is what fixed it for me. Puzzling that bundler seems to be the only one to use this variable.

Comment: Also worked for me exporting the upper case HTTP_PROXY rather than lower case.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to set a global variable in the system you can edit ~/.gemrc and write it like that

```
---
:benchmark: false
:verbose: true
:sources:
- http://rubygems.org/
- http://gems.rubyforge.org
:backtrace: false
:bulk_threshold: 1000
:update_sources: true
gem: --http-proxy=http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@ADDRESS:PORT
```

Comment: Unfortunately bundler ignores that.

Answer (score 5):

to get bundler behind a proxy on win XP/7 I needed to do the following:

I added http_proxy to the Environment Variables

- My Computer
- Advanced system settings
- Advanced Tab Environment
- Variables
- New
- Variable name = http_proxy
- Variable value = MY_PROXY
- Click Ok

Change MY_PROXY to whatever yours is.

this worked for bundler. The .gemrc proxy setting only worked for gems.

thanks
Jamie

Comment: Instead of doing it on the Environment, I just added it before calling bundle, using `SET HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@www.proxy.com`

Comment: i would prefer more flexible and securable way:

SET /P login="Enter proxy login: "
SET /P password="Enter proxy password: "
SET HTTP_PROXY=http://%login%:%password%@proxy.com:8080
SET HTTPS_PROXY=%HTTP_PROXY%

CLS

Answer (score 3):

You can download the required gems locally with gem install and then bundle install.  Not exactly neat, I know, but it does work.

Answer (score 3):

probably more flexible and securable use batch file:

```
SET /P login="Enter proxy login: "
SET /P password="Enter proxy password: "
SET HTTP_PROXY=http://%login%:%password%@proxy.com:8080
SET HTTPS_PROXY=%HTTP_PROXY%

CLS

bundle install
```

Comment: Like the idea, but this doesn't work with special characters in the password :/

Answer (score 1):

Windows OS, run following command before execute `bundle install`

```
SET http_proxy=http://user:password@host:port
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your OS default http_proxy is already set up. If you're using Linux try the following command to know which proxy it's pointing to.

```
echo $http_proxy
```

In my Ubuntu OS, I set my http_proxy environment variable to my proxy server in ~/.bashrc

Comment: Yes, that works for many things, but as I stated, Bundler seems to ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ export http_proxy="http://username:password@host:port"
$ export ftp_proxy="http://username:password@host:port"
$ sudo visudo
```

Add this line in the file:

```
Defaults env_keep = "http_proxy ftp_proxy"
```

Above this line:

```
Defaults        env_reset
```

then run your command as sudo it will work.

ref :https://memset.wordpress.com/2010/10/14/bash-http_proxy-from-a-user-environment-to-sudo-one/

Answer (score 0):

I am running Ubuntu.  The $http_proxy variable is set, but it doesn't work with a couple items.  One of those items being gem.

If you put the following in your ~/.gemrc it will work.

http_proxy: proxy-url:port

Replace the proxy-url:port with your proxy address and port.  After I added that, I ran "bundle install" and everything ran as expected.

Answer (score 0):

To have command `bundle install` work with proxy on windows do the following:

1. Edit file `.gemrc`. Open windows command line and type: `notepad %userprofile%\.gemrc` .
2. The file .gemrc is open in notepad. Type on a new line `http_proxy: 
   http://username:passwordEncodedWithUrlencode@proxyaddress:proxyport` . Password should be encoded with urlencode .
3. Close the file .gemrc with saving it.