# Is there a way to setup a minimal rubygems mirror (with only last versions)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, mirror

I want to build a rubygems mirror accesible for some servers at work (that don't have Internet access), so I started like everybody seems to do:

```
 $ cat gemmirror.config 
 ---
 - from: http://gems.rubyforge.org
 to: /data/rubygems/mirror

 $ gem mirror --config-file=gemmirror.config
```

The mirror starts syncing well. OK. But wait, it downloads the whole content of http://gems.rubyforge.org! I mean all the existing versions of every single gem. Wow. After a couple of hours I'm still downloading the gems that begin with the letter "L" ...

Not to mention the disk-space the mirror is going to take.

Now my question: is there a way to setup a "mini" rubygems server, like CPAN::Mini allows for Perl: such a mirror would contain only the latest version of every gems. This is in 99.9% of the cases what people want, I guess (at least this would be perfectly good enough for me there).

I've googled a lot and sadly, I cannot find any reference to that.

If someone can point me to the way to do that, I'd appreciate very much.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not really what you are asking for, but perhaps one way to tackle this, is to setup a caching http proxy that will cache the gems as they are requested, which should subsequent requests hit the cache.

Something like [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) should do the job.

Then each client configures the [gem proxy](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/13) to use squid, so all gem downloads go through it and hopefully are in the cache 99% of the time...

Although if you use bundler, seems it [has issues with the proxy settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877055/how-to-use-bundler-behind-a-proxy) :(