# rails 'bundle install' - Do it manually?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, installation, bundler

**Problem:**
Due to proxy settings i am not able to execute 'bundle install' from comandline. I get the following error. I dont know the proxy settings and i want to continue with rails development.

```
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Could not reach rubygems repository http://rubygems.org/
Could not find gem 'capybara (>= 0)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Ge
mfile.
```

**Question:**
How can we do 'bundle install' manually (downloading gems via browser and install in commandline)? I need to install only handlful of gems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will *have* to setup a proxy. If not for now, for later when your app grows. Downloading all your gems via browser will become tedious and an horrible mess.

See related question on [how to use bundler behind a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877055/how-to-use-bundler-behind-a-proxy).

Comment: Can i setup a local repository (by downloading all gems manually) in my drive and use it with bundler?

Comment: You could probably download all your necessary gems and put them into your project’s `vendor/cache` directory and then run: `bundle install --local`

Comment: I see that it's not a good diea to download manually :) Even worse is trying to setup a mirror (It's about 100GB of data!)