# Why does bundler always fail on my University's network?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

When I try `bundle install` in my University I always get:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:239:in `rescue in
fetch_path': SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known     
(http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/kgio-2.8.0.gemspec.rz) (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
```

I hear the similar problems from other fellow students particularly when they are trying to install sqlite.

Comment: Can you access rubygems.org with your browser?

Comment: @Mindbreaker yes, the page is loading.

Comment: definitely a connection issue. probably firewall settings or something.

Comment: Perhaps you need to use a proxy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877055/how-to-use-bundler-behind-a-proxy

Answer (score 0):

I had some similar problems at my university.  If your university has a VPN you can connect to, as well as their wireless internet, I would try connecting to that and then try "bundle install" again.