# installing gems without bundler -Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler

I have a working project in my personal laptop using Rails 3. I checked out that project on my work laptop. When I'm in the office I  can't use bundle install due to come company policies. Hence, unfortunately I have to manually install all the gems. How can I get my app running without wasting my time on resolving the gems dependencies that bundler would have done easily. Gemfile:

```
    source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.10'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

#gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'pg','0.12.2'
gem 'therubyracer'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'devise'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

group :test do
  # Pretty printed test output
  gem 'turn', '0.8.2', :require => false
end
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why can't you use Bundler at your company ?

Comment: for some reasons i dnt know but i cannot connect to rubygems.org...there is a proxy setup.@Arkan

Comment: If you can't connect to rubygems.org you could try pulling them from github. gem 'rails', :git => .....

Comment: Maybe this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877055/how-to-use-bundler-behind-a-proxy

Comment: Do your work at work, not side projects! ;)

Comment: sorry @Micharch54..i am unable to use it....as i cannot connect because   of proxy

Comment: thanks @Arkan for the link ..but it didnt help as i am using windows 7

Answer (score 2):

Simply wite the following commonds on terminal

```
gem install pg -v='0.12.2'
gem install therubyracer
gem install jquery-rails
gem install devise
gem install turn -v=0.8.2
```