# Bundle install not working, showing fatal error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On bundle install command, its showing "fatal: unable to access 'https://github.xxxx.com' : couldnot resolve the host: github.xxxx.com"
I tried clearing cache,but also getting same issue. Can someone help me fixing this issue?

Comment: github.xxxx.com? use correct github hostname

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877055/how-to-use-bundler-behind-a-proxy

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I was running ruby on mac (virtual box), I just restarted it two to three times which i did previously also and the problem got fixed. Wondering still what was the issue, It simply killed my time . But thanks for the replies. :)