# bundle install won't work: Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from rubygems.org

Tags: ruby, windows, bundle

I am trying to run `bundle install` on a VM that is behind a proxy.
I am getting the following error:

```
Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from rubygems.org
```

If I try to ping this then `Request timed out`

However, I can browse to the website, which makes this strange to me.

Any suggestions how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Your Browser may have its own Proxy Settings.

Maybe you should set the `HTTP_PROXY/HTTPS_PROXY` environment variables.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4496648

Comment: thanks for coming back. i had discovered that thread before. in the end, i just ditched my vm, spun up another and my problem had gone away. however, this was as good a suggestion as any. thanks